# JQuery on the server only intermittently .appends()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

As per below, I am calling an endpoint when the page is loaded to get some data and append it to a div. On localhost it works perfectly, but on the server it only works intermittently... When I look in dev tools, the network tab suggests the $.post works and returns the data... but the append doesn't.

I wondered if it was to do with the $.post completing before the html was rendered, so there was no div to append to... but not sure how to verify or fix this. I've tried moving the script in the html page to just before the close-body tag to ensure the html is rendered first. I've also made sure i define the functions in the JS before the `$(Document).ready` is called.

To see it not working LIVE... [www.everythingproduct.com](http://www.everythingproduct.com) - If you try clicking on the blogs page multiple times, you'll see sometimes it hangs...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var page = 'blog-articles';
  $('#main-body-content').load('site/pages/' + page + '.php');
  loadArticlesData();

  $.post('endpoint/sendEvent.php', {
    userID: '<?php echo $uid; ?>',
    eventType: "pageView",
    currentURL: window.location.href,
    referer: '<?php echo $referer; ?>'
  });

});

function loadArticlesData() {
  $('#cover').show();
  $.post('endpoint/getArticles.php', {
    type: "All"
  }, function(result) {
    var data = result;
    $.each(data, function(i, l) {
      $('#articles').append(
        '<a target="_blank" href="' + l.link + '">' +
        '<div value="' + l.id + '" class="article">' +
        '<div class="img">' +
        '<img src="img/' + l.img + '" height="50px">' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="article-content">' +
        '<h2>' + l.title + '</h2>' +
        '<span class="description-text">' + l.description + '... <span style="font-style: italic; color: #888;">See more</span></span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</a>'
      );
    });
    $('#cover').fadeOut("slow");
  });

  $.post('endpoint/getTags.php', {}, function(result) {
    var data = result;

    $.each(data, function(i, l) {
      $('#tags').append(
        '<span value="' + l + '" class="tag-word">' + l + '</span> '
      );
    });
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cover"></div>
<div class="body">
  <div class="body-container">
    <div class="body-left">
      <div style="text-align: left; padding-left: 20px;">
        <h1 style="font-weight: normal;">Blog Article Database</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="articles" class="articles"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="body-right">
      <div class="filter-panel">
        <h3>Browse (A-Z)</h3>
        <div id="tags" class="tags">
          <span style="background: #fff; color: #0c7bce;" value="ALL" class="tag-word">ALL</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are interfering with the asynchronous requests. Only do one at a time and continue in the success

Try this:

```
$('#main-body-content').load('site/pages/' + page + '.php',  loadArticlesData);
```

to wait until the first request is done - then move

`$.post('endpoint/getTags.php', {}...`

into the end of the success of the second request